# What happens if I remove the @EJB annotation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb-3.0

I read the article on:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBean

Just wondering:
What will happen if I remove the @EJB annotation?

Comment: Probably your wiki edit will soon be rolled back by someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you refer to the second exemple of code in this page.

If you remove the `@EJB` annotation, dependency injection isn't done anymore on this attribute.

In this case, it means that the reference to the `CustomerServiceLocal` EJB will never be injected in your current instance, and, in this case, any call to the `addCustomer()` method will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Just to get things right: an EJB cannot be referred as helper class allocated in memory? Sorry for the somewhat beginner's question. I couldn't find any decent explanation for that in the last few days. All I see - is that EJB is always referred using @EJB.

Comment: You can reference EJBs from a helper class, but you have to use JNDI (new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejbrefname")) rather than dependency injection.  Alternatively, you could use JCDI.